# Update entity with foreign key object reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In entity framework I have two entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have two`Child` s in database:

```
Id: 1, Name: "First"
Id: 2, Name: "Second"
```

I also have one `Parent` with properties:

```
Id: 1, Name: "Parent", Child_Id: 1
```

Now I am trying to change the foreign key like this:

```
using (var c = new Context())
{
    var parent = c.Parents.First(record => record.Id == 1);
    parent.Child = new Child(2, "Second")
    c.SaveChanges();
}
```

But it gives the error:

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
>   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

Explain why and give the solution of how to achieve my goal please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I was creating Child in different context like this:

`parent.Child = new Child(2, "Second")`

Instead I had to get the object from the given context like this:

```
parent.Child = c.Childs.Find(2);
```

Comment: By the way, in parent-child relation, it's better to link child item into parent node. So it's better to add ParentId property to Child class and load Parent in Child element virtually.